# Magento Paypal Standard 302

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

I'm intermittently getting a 302 error like below.

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/paypal/standard/redirect/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
```

Sometimes it works (200), sometimes it fails and just returns to homepage.

I put some debug code in

```
Mage/Paypal/controllers/StandardController.php
```

but when it fails it doesn't even use this file.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze the request which going to Paypal in the following file:

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php`

In above file, there is a function called `getStandardCheckoutFormFields` in which you can trace

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it doesn't get that far when it fails.